# How to verify multiple host cache cluster settings

Tags: caching, appfabric

I have a few questions regarding AppFabric Caching.

Q 1. 
I have set up an AppFabric Cache cluster with two hosts, say Host1 and Host2. I have registered both the hosts on Host1 machine with SQL Server provider.

My client config looks like this:

```
<hosts>
    <host name="Host1" cachePort="22233" />
</hosts>
```

Now, when I run my client, every time the values are being stored in Host1 and never on Host2. Is this just by co-incidence or is there anything wrong with my setup? How do I verify if both the hosts are available in the cluster?

---

Update on the above question: 
If I modify my client configuration to include the other host, i.e.

```
<hosts>
    <host name="Host1" cachePort="22233" />
    <host name="Host2" cachePort="22233" />
</hosts>
```

then, it does pick up Host2 some times to store the data. But as far as I understand, I do not need to specify all the hosts from a cluster in the client config. Is that correct?

Q 2. 
Is there a way to change the CachePort of a host. I could update the other ports using Set-CacheHostConfig, but not the CachePort.

Q 3. Any other guidelines while setting up a cache cluster with multiple hosts?

Appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the cachePort using `Set-CacheHostConfig`, the cachePort parameter you set here is used to tell the commandlet which port to communicate with the host on. You can set the port during installation (or by running the configuration wizard again):
[image: Set the AppFabric CachePort during installation]

I'd think carefully before doing this though, you'll need to remmeber to set the port number correctly in all your web.configs, and anything you install that assumes the default port will also fail (and this strikes me as something that'll be really hard to remember when you're debugging).